# div does not expand again in my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner to the front-end technologies and javascript. I found an example on how to expand and collapse a div and currently trying to implement the same on my web page. But the div collapses and does not expand again when i click on the image. Can some please check my code.

here is my html code:

```
<div id="headerDivImg">
    <a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle5('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="file:///C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/AP%20Report/img/arrow486.png"></a>
    <label><b>LAST PAGE/STARTER PLATE </b>
</div>
<div id="contentDivImg">This demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.</div>
```

Below is the javascript:

```
function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="file:///C:/Users/seemanapallik/Documents/AP%20Report/img/arrow486.png">';
        }
        else {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="file:///C:/Users/seemanapallik/Documents/AP%20Report/img/play106.png">';
        }
}
```

I tried in many ways by modifying both html and javascript code, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You’re setting the display property to block when it already _is_ block … it needs to be the other way around, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is your culprit. If the display is set to block, you set it to block again, otherwise you set it to none. It should be the other way around :

```
if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
} else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: If i change the code as above, on page load the div is expanded. But if I click the image, div does not collapse. Again on click, the div collapses. Whereas I want do see the div expanded on page load and when I click on the image the div should collapse.

Comment: This worked:

if(ele.style.display == "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
                ele.style.display = "none";
        }